# Using "grow" in a subject + verb collocation

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, verbs

I have a problem with the usage of the word “grow.”

Sentence 1: The wings grow.

Sentence 2: The chick grows wings.

I know “the hair grows” but not “I grow my hair.” But how about the sentences above? Are there any nuances?

Comment: What makes you believe that only one of the options is correct?

Comment: @KillingTime You mean both of them are correct?

Comment: *I grow my hair long in the winter, then shave my head on the vernal equinox* Nothing wrong with the grammar there.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Thank you for your example! I understand it now. :)

Comment: The wings grow (get bigger). A man grows a beard (allows it to grow). Saying that a chick grows wings implies that it hatches without any (it doesn't, they're just small and without feathers).

Comment: _Grow_ can be either a  volitional verb (_He grows zucchini in that box_) or it can be just a factor of development. People and animals and plants and mushrooms grow; and metaphorically, anything -- abstract or concrete -- can be said to _grow_ if it gains mass, area, age, prestige, or any other measurable property. That's the intransitive use, as in _Insects grow their exoskeleton before they grow their legs_. The transitive use, like growing zucchini, takes a direct object and may or may not be interpreted as being on purpose: _He grew a beard/He grew a wart_.

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks. Your explanation is very clear.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thank you. The examples are very useful for me to comprehend it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OP's utterance *The chick grows wings* is not a "felicitous / happy" use of the verb ***to grow***. If you want the wings to be the subject (a perfectly acceptable stylistic choice), it's better to say...

> *The chick's wings **develop.***

Personally, I wouldn't say *The chick develops **its** wings*, because that implies a deliberate act by the chick. That implication is far weaker with my preferred version with the chick as the subject...

> *The chick **develops** wings.*

Comment: Thanks. I understand it. :)